# Transformation into Martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingale, differential-equations, sde

If $f$ is some function of BV on $\mathbb{R}$ and $dZ_t = f(W_t)dW_t + \mu_t dt$   ($W_t$ is a $1$-dimensional standard Brownian Motion), then what choice of real valued function $F$ makes:
\begin{equation}
M_t:= Z_t e^{\int_0^tF(Z_t)dt}
\end{equation}
into a martingale?

I feel that I sould use Ito's product rule to solve this and the fact that the term $e^{\int_0^tF(Z_t)dt}$ must be of B.V. (since it is a Riemman integral), however I'm fuzzy on the details (as I'm completetly new to this type of problem).

Thanks for your help all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have guessed correctly, these type of questions can be answered using Ito's Lemma.We have:
\begin{equation}
d(M_t)= d(Z_t e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du})=d(Z_t) e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du}+Z_t d(e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du})+d(Z_t)d(e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du})
\end{equation}

For the first two terms on R.H.S, we have:
\begin{equation}
d(Z_t) e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du} = (f(W_t)dW_t + \mu_t dt) e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du}
\end{equation}

and 
\begin{equation}
Z_t d(e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du}) = Z_t e^{\int_0^tF(Z_u)du}F(Z_t)dt
\end{equation}

the third term does not contribute anything.

Now,  for martingale condition to hold, equate the coefficient of time dependent term to zero and we get

\begin{equation}
F(Z_t) = -\mu_t/Z_t 
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$F=0$ seems like a good choice.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question,  I forgot the drift which made it a bit trivial